# Deploy Spring MVC on Heroku

Tags: spring-mvc, heroku

I want to try to deploy the app on heroku. Created a simple MVC Spring that outputs "Hello Mark" in the browser. The app works. I follow the instructions.
Call:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1

Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

And when you open the app

---

Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

---

The logs show an error:

```
2020-10-01T16:36:04.081129+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user mark.sinakaev@gmail.com
2020-10-01T16:36:04.081129+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user mark.sinakaev@gmail.com
2020-10-01T16:36:04.325650+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user mark.sinakaev@gmail.com
2020-10-01T16:36:04.325650+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user mark.sinakaev@gmail.com
2020-10-01T16:38:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mark.sinakaev@gmail.com
2020-10-01T16:38:36.880432+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user mark.sinakaev@gmail.com
2020-10-01T16:38:36.880432+00:00 app[api]: Deploy ab380bda by user mark.sinakaev@gmail.com
2020-10-01T16:38:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-10-01T16:42:01.754283+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=sinakaev.herokuapp.com request_id=1b73c233-00df-4d63-abe3-b406bbd75fbc fwd="95.30.16.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-01T16:42:02.130866+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sinakaev.herokuapp.com request_id=40a7902a-9cd9-43f1-a693-66aa96ad1bf1 fwd="95.30.16.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-01T16:59:27.106572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=sinakaev.herokuapp.com request_id=74ad276a-e21b-4960-9e5a-b460ec0f2fca fwd="95.30.16.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-01T16:59:27.403649+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sinakaev.herokuapp.com request_id=53fdb320-c269-4d38-bd27-f88f46b84256 fwd="95.30.16.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Give me an idea, please, how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#the-web-process-type)? You should define your `web` process in that file, and then you can scale up the `web` dyno before sending traffic.